# Props arguments are not reactive in setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

I'm trying to develop a component that compiles the given html; I succeeded with constant html texts, but I can't make this work with changing html texts.

**main.js**

```
app.component("dyno-html", {
  props: ["htmlTxt"],
  setup(props) {
    watchEffect(() => {
      console.log(`htmlText is: ` + props.htmlTxt);
      return compile(props.htmlTxt);
    });
    return compile(props.htmlTxt);
  },
});
```

**Home.js**

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <dyno-html
      :htmlTxt="html2"
      :bound="myBoundVar"
      @buttonclick="onClick"
    ></dyno-html>
    -------------
    <dyno-html
      :htmlTxt="html"
      :bound="myBoundVar"
      @buttonclick="onClick"
    ></dyno-html>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {},
  data: function() {
    return {
      html: "",
      html2: `<div> Static! <button @click="$emit('buttonclick', $event)">CLICK ME</button></div>`
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // get the html from somewhere...
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.html = `
        <div>
          Dynamic!
          <button @click="$emit('buttonclick', $event)">CLICK ME</button>
        </div>
      `;
    }, 1000);
  },
  methods: {
    onClick(ev) {
      console.log(ev);
      console.log("You clicked me!");
      this.html2 = "<b>Bye Bye!</b>";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Outcome:**
[image: Outcome]

**Console:**
[image: Console output]

It seems the changes of `htmlText` arrives to setup function, but it doesn't affect the compile function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour because prop value is read once and results in static render function.

Prop value should be read inside render function. It can be wrapped with a computed to avoid unneeded compiler calls:

```
const textCompRef = computed(() => ({ render: compile(props.htmlTxt) }));
return () => h(textCompRef.value);
```

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I was looking for!
Do you know how I can use it in nested manner? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539202/)