# How to define properties in nested Vue3 compiling dynamic-html?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to use Vue compiler to render dynamic HTML texts; I have implemented this component:

```
app.component("dyno-html", {
  props: ["htmlTxt"],
  setup(props) {
    const textCompRef = computed(() => ({ render: compile(props.htmlTxt) }));
    return () => h(textCompRef.value);
  },
});
```

I have succeeded in doing so, in one level. Like the code below, and it works fine.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <dyno-html :htmlTxt="htmlTest"></dyno-html>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {},
  data: function() {
    return {
      htmlTest: "<H1>Test</H1>",
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to add a second layer in a nested manner:

```
htmlTest: "<h1>Test</h1><dyno-html :htmlTxt='htmlTest2'></dyno-html>",
htmlTest2: "<h2>Test2</h2>",
```

I get this warning:

> [Vue warn]: Property "htmlTest2" was accessed during render but is not
> defined on instance.

Resulting into the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: template is undefined

Comment: htmlTest likely needs to be a computed that concatenates template string with htmlTest2 value, but most likely this is XY problem. You wouldn't need a compiler to output html only; there's v-html for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask , The idea is not use simple html... I'm going step-by-step. 
The idea is there are functions that calculates the look of the page. In the middle of work, the function might decide to add a new part to the page. I thought instead of replacing the whole htmlTest; I only change the part htmlTest2.... so maybe it renders faster...

Comment: If you want to optimize a part of the render, extract it to a separate component, but I doubt that this will help with dynamically compiled components because they are different components on each change and won't benefit from optimization.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks, I actually tried that too! I can't import the components. They have to be global. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541462