# Vue $options.template works only once

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I try to build a dynamic Vue component, where I pass a template string as prop and want the component to render it.

`this.$options.template = this.htmlString;`

This seemed to work fine until I tried to change the template. I can't get the component to rerender, when `htmlString` changes. Is there a way to do this?

I also tried the `render` function and `Vue.compile` but I don't really know how to use them. This throws errors:

```
render(createElement) {
  return Vue.compile(this.htmlString).render(createElement);
}
```

Vue 2.6

Comment: Which errors? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69526956/props-arguments-are-not-reactive-in-setup/69532204#69532204 . In V2 I'd expect it to be `return createElement(Vue.compile(this.htmlString))`

Comment: ``createElement(Vue.compile(this.htmlString))`` does the trick! I don't understand why, but it works.

Comment: I'd expect initial code to work, but this way is cleaner and doesn't rely on `render` internals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 2 `compile` returns an object with `render` method. Since Vue component is an object that is supposed to have either `render` or `template` property, an object is identified as a component by `createElement` and can be passed to it directly:

```
render(createElement) {
  return createElement(Vue.compile(this.htmlString));
}
```

`compile` can be moved to a computed in order to skip unnecessary calls:

```
computed: {
  HtmlComp() {
    return Vue.compile(this.htmlString);
  }
},
render(createElement) {
  return createElement(this.HtmlComp);
}
```

The same [applies to Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69526956/props-arguments-are-not-reactive-in-setup/69532204#69532204), adjusted for changes in API.